# I get HTTP 500 error when use python urllib2.open

Tags: python, urllib2

The code is like. The url is my blog and I'd like to fetch and backup my blog posts. Things goes well with my other blog posts but return 500 error with this one.

```
usock = urlopen("http://xiaoshuaistudio.ycool.com/post.4606754.html")
htmlSource = usock.read()
usock.close()
```

Can you help me figure out how to debug a HTTP 500 error?

Comment: 500 is a generic HTTP error. Read the server logs; this has nothing to do with urllib.

Answer (score 3):

A page content is loaded, and a 500 error is returned. But I myself can't read whether the page content is relevant.

To avoid error on this specific page or website you could do (**WARNING** this is not very pretty)

```
try:
  response = urlopen(url)
  content = response.read()
except HTTPError, e:
  if e.getcode() == 500:
    content = e.read()
  else:
    raise
```

Comment: The following HTML parsing logic fails for the `content` from `content = e.read()`. So now I think something is wrong with the article itself. Maybe encoding error like @lostyzd suggested that server knows but human don't. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Legend - needed the `e.read()` as wanted the content of the page even on a non-200 response (e.g. 500). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the server logs on your web server.  In general, error data will be safe on the server.  It's not a good idea to dump error logs to users.

Comment: The `ycool.com` is a blog provider like `blogspot.com` of Google. So it's impossible to see the logs. Or could you suggest possible reason of the 500 error. I'm sure there should be a reason because only this post returns error. Maybe it's too long? Data too large?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the `ycool.com` server, because I couldn't open this url with my web browser.

`http://xiaoshuaistudio.ycool.com/post.4606754.html`

That web server will always return `status code 500 Internal Server Error` for some url, which should be `200 OK`.

If the `urlopen` function only check for the status code, it will return that error(Although the server send that page's content).

Comment: my browser can perfectly open this page, while urllib2 can't, there is a real problem...

Comment: @CédricJulien It is due to your explorer, I test on my chrome and firefox browser.

Comment: @lostyzd I observed the same phenomenon as you did. The server send full content but a 500 error code. What can that be?

Comment: @lostyzd : When opening the dev tools of Chrome I saw that the server send a HTTP 500 error, even if the page is correctly downloaded and displayed, maybe the server's dev confused 500 and 200 ;).

Comment: @hbrlovehaku I think you should report this bug to the server's dev. It might be an encoding error.

Comment: I reported. They didn't respond. I choose to skip this post. But I will keep on with debugging the potential encoding error. Thanks.