# Error 500 while using urllib2 on an asp form which redirects

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

So if i go to the address directly, it redirects, and loads the page i want, but if i try to do it using the code below, it gives error code 500;

```
import urllib, urllib2

import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    molecule = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Error: no molecule requested"
    sys.exit()

# Created handler
redirectionHandler = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler() 

# 2 apply the handler to an opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirectionHandler)

# 3. Install the openers
urllib2.install_opener(opener)


request = urllib2.Request("http://cccbdb.nist.gov/getform.asp", data=urllib.urlencode({'formula':molecule, "submit1": "Submit"}))
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

use the program by just doing something like `python program.py ch4`, and it will throw the error. Just visiting the link works fine however;

for example http://cccbdb.nist.gov/getform.asp?formula=ch4

what i want to do, is fill out the form at [this](http://cccbdb.nist.gov/geom1.asp) page, and then load the results page. That page has this:

```
<FORM action="getform.asp" method=POST id=form1 >
<INPUT type="text" id=text1 name=formula
VALUE='CH4'
></P>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" id=submit1 name=submit1>
</FORM>
```

and when i submit the post data directly to that page, it gives me exactly what i want. When i do it using urllib2 it gives the error 500. I have tried doing it simply, without setting up the redirection stuff, and also tried to catch the error and ignore it while taking any content too (as per [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404938/i-get-http-500-error-when-use-python-urllib2-open) answer).

`$ wget http://cccbdb.nist.gov/getform.asp?formula=ch4` doesn't work either.

**How can I get the content of this page in python?**

EDIT:
I have just tried it using `mechanize` too, and i get the same error;

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

import sys


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    molecule = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Error: no molecule requested"
    sys.exit()


# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
#br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('http://cccbdb.nist.gov/geom1.asp')

# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)

br.form["formula"] = molecule

br.submit()
```

Comment: Any `onSubmit` handlers registered for the form? It might be a CSRF protection in effect.

Comment: Also, filling the form and examining the data sent to the server, I see that the request method is `POST` and `submit1:Submit` passed along with the formula parameter. Try adding `'submit1':Submit` to the data dictionary and ensure that data is requested using `POST` method.

Comment: @JOHN i just added the "submit1":"Submit" to the dictionary sent, it still gives the same error.

How could CSRF detect whether i'm using a browser, or just the python?

Comment: CSRF is an attack technique. One possible approach to address the risk of CSRF attacks is to check the `Referer` http-header, or to embed some token to the form at runtime. If `Referer` or token does not match what the server expects, the server just refuses the request. But I wouldn't throw 500 error in such a case, so it's unlikely the CSRF protection. I think most likely your code uses `GET` method, and server expects `POST`.

Comment: And one more possible source of error: the `getform.asp` redirects to `geom2.asp` with no parameters at all. All that passed to the `geom2.asp` is the `ASPSESSIONIDACARDBQT` cookie. So, you probably need to add cookie jar handler to urllib request.

Comment: I seem to have solved the problem, and now it's working as expected. I'll post the code in a bit, once it's finished...

Comment: @JOHN and yes I am doing it using a cookiejar